# Getting Python to return more than one value to Java

Tags: java, python

I used the information from [this link](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java) to write the following code below to run a Python script and have it return a single string returned:

```
public static void Option_2_Output()
    {
        Scanner Option2_Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("          Testing Means of Two Groups          ");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("");

        String Option2_program = "python";
        String Option2_path = "C:\\PathtoScript\\Python_Test.py";

        try{

            String Option2_datapath;
            System.out.print("Please type the location of your Data : ");
            Option2_datapath = Option2_Input.next();

            ProcessBuilder Option2_process = new ProcessBuilder(Option2_program,Option2_path,"" + Option2_datapath);
            Process Option2_Output = Option2_process.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Option2_Output.getInputStream()));
            String Option2_Final = new String(in.readLine());
            System.out.println(Option2_Final);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

    }
```

The object `Option2_Final` streams the last printed output from the Python script back as a string. How do I get more than one value back?

Comment: What do you expect? You just ran one `readLine()`.

Comment: Wow now I feel dumb lol I should have known better thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one line is being streamed back because there's only one `readLine()` function being utilized.  A for-loop could be written to search for each additional line or objects could be created for each line you're intending to pass back:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Option2_Output.getInputStream()));
            String Option2_Final_1 = new String(in.readLine()); //Line 1
            String Option2_Final_2 = new String(in.readLine()); //Line 2
            System.out.println(Option2_Final_1); //Print Line 1
            System.out.println(Option2_Final); //Print Line 2
```